# Access-Control-Origin Error

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to call a PHP function on an ASP.Net CMS. I'm hosting the PHP file on a different domain and I'm getting the following error.

XMLHttpRequest cannot load url. Origin url is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

I've added header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); to the PHP file as per some suggestions in other threads on this site, but it hasn't made a difference for me.

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
       $.post('http://10.254.2.54/adobe%20air/application/Pulse/data.php', {
             'text': $("#preceda").text()
        },

        function(response){

          $("#details").html(response);

         });

   }); 

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="preceda">
  32384
</div>

<br />
<div id="details"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP

```
<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

if ( isset($_POST['text']) ){
   $q = addslashes(trim($_POST['text']));
}

// Connection script
$serverName = "***";
$uid = "***";
$pwd = "***";
$connectionInfo = array("UID"=>$uid, "PWD"=>$pwd, "Database"=>"***");

$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

if($conn === false)
{
  echo "<error>Connect Failure</error>";
  die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

function checkQuery($theQuery, $theSQL)
{
  if($theQuery === false)
  {
    echo "<error>Query Failure: ".$theSQL."</error>";
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
  }
}

// Get the data
$tsql = "SELECT * FROM VG_LD_DS.dbo.VU_LearnAchievePreceda WHERE userID = '".$q."'";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql);
checkQuery($stmt, $tsql);

$i = 0;

while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
  {
    if($i == 0)
    {
      $names = array($row);
    }
    else
    {
      array_push($names, $row);
    }
    $i = 1;
  }
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
foreach ($names as $name) {
   echo $name['telstraID'];
}

?>
```

This stuff is fairly new to me, so any advice or suggestion are appreciated.

Thank you :)

Comment: can't see how any of that code would cause a same-origin violation... are you sure your ajax request isn't being redirect off-site somewhere?

Comment: Yes it is sorry, I guess it isn't clear from my code. The data.php is being hosted on a different internal server to the page with the ajax request.

Comment: This can be done using JSONP or `CURL`

Comment: @diEcho Unfortunately this is beyond my skillset. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, here's my solution:

create a js file at the domain as the php api.

use the `<script type="text/javascript" src="path to js file"></script>` tag

call your functions inside that script

as it is in the same domain as the .php you won't run into the cross-domain restriction problem ;)

Comment: I transferred the script to a JS file on the same domain as the PHP file and unfortunately I got the same error :( Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: did you change the locations in the file to localhost or something?

Comment: No, i did leave the full address in the JS file which I put on the same domain as the PHP file. I just tried removing the full address in the JS to have just 'data.php', however the browser then looks like it tries to look for it within the other domain.

Answer (score 0):

If your code really is:

```
$.post('data.php', ...
```

Then it should work fine. However, in your description of the problem it appears that you're trying to do this instead:

```
$.post('http://some.other.domain.com/data.php', ...
```

This is not allowed because it breaks the browser's same origin policy (which cannot be overridden by the programmer, only the user and even then only in some browsers). XMLHttpRequest can only be made to url's of the same domain.

The standard work around for this is to proxy the request through your ASP server. So for example you'll make a request like:

```
$.post('data.asp', ...
```

And `data.asp` is simply a script that fetches the `data.php` response via HTTP. There are no restrictions server side. Depending on the server, you can even do this without any scripting by using proxy or redirect modules in the server config. For example, you can configure Apache with mod-rewrite to proxy the page like this:

```
RewriteRule /data.php http://some.other.domain.com/data.php [P]
```

There are other solutions that doesn't require proxying such as the script tag hack (otherwise known as jsonp, google it). Some libraries like YUI can do cross domain ajax call by using Flash modules to bypass the browser's same origin policy. Flash generally doesn't have restriction of same origin policy which is why you can embed youtube videos on your website.

Comment: Thank you for your extensive response. My stumbling block here would be writing an ASP script to fetch the data.php script. I wouldn't know where to start with that one. I'll google the script tag hack and see what I can get out of it.